# 'CoinEffect' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity for the first time and a friend of mine gave me a link to [Brackey's Unity Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6s9RO8pZZc) of which I'm on part 9, the Unity Particle System. The tutorial uses JavaScript and was made 7 years ago, Unity now only uses C# and so I can't for the life of me figure out why my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoinEffect : MonoBehaviour {
Transform coinEffect;

void  OnTriggerEnter ( Collider info  ){
    if (info.tag == "Player") {
        Debug.Log("Coin Picked Up");
        Instantiate(CoinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

It's seriously got me stumped so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your `Instantiate` call, you wrote `CoinEffect` (uppercase C), which is the class, not `coinEffect` (lowercase C), which is the field. Identifiers are case sensitive in C#, so you have to pick the right one.

Comment: If the `Instantiate` call takes a `Type` as the first parameter, use `typeof(CoinEffect)` to get the Type as an object

Comment: @Flydog57 `Instantiate` takes either a game object or a component of a game object and clones said game object. Passing a `Transform` component that was assigned from a prefab to `Instantiate` is a pretty common pattern in Unity. Hence my guess that the author really wanted the first parameter to be `coinEffect`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be tempted to leave a lot of the processing up to the new Particle System.

```
[RequireComponent ( typeof ( ParticleSystem ) )]
public class CoinEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    // An example renderer. This assumes there's a MeshRenderer to be turned off.
    // Might be SpriteRenderer, so this needs to be swapped out for the right renderer.
    public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    private ParticleSystem _ps;

    private void Awake ( )
    {
        _ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ( );
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider info )
    {
        if ( info.CompareTag ( "Player" ) )
        {
            Debug.Log ( "Coin Picked Up" );
            _ps.Play ( );
            meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that the Particle System Main Module has a *Stop Action*. Use this to determine what you'd like to do when the Particle System stops playing. You might also want to disable whatever renderer you have on the triggered object. And, as previously suggested, use the *Stop Action* to destroy the whole GameObject.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, or help follow the tutorial.